# How to click an element on webpage only showing <li class="" data-type=""

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to develop a VBA internet explorer automation solution. I have a link that I would like to click, inspecting the element I get `<li class="expMenuItem listTypes dataTypeMaterialId" data-type="MaterialId">Substance Identifier</li>`. What would be the proper code for this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to use VBA or JavaScript to programmatically click a (hyper)link that already exists on a web page? An li element is not a link.

Comment: I am just asking what would be the appropriate method in this case, I know getElementbyID and getElementsByName, but I can't use those in this case. Perhaps I shouldn't use the word link, element would be more appropriate, but when this element is click a certain javascript is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> *"I am just asking what would be the appropriate method in this case, I know `getElementbyID` and `getElementsByName`, but I can't use those in this case."*

You seem to be asking how to select an element so as to assign a click handler to it, when the only thing you have to select it by is a class name or a `data-` attribute.

You can select elements that have a certain class using the [`.getElementsByClassName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName). Note that it returns an HTMLCollection of matching elements, so you have to check that the result has a `.length` of 1 if you expect exactly one element, or process the result in a loop if you expect multiple elements:

```
var elmts = document.getElementsByClassName("dataTypeMaterialId");
if (elmts.length === 1 )
  elmts[0].addEventListener("click", function() { /* do something */ }, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zw3g69ry/1/

Alternatively you can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to select a single element based on a CSS style selector, or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) to select multiple elements matching a CSS style selector:

```
var elmt = document.querySelector('[data-type="MaterialId"]')
if (elmt)
  elmt.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* do something */
      alert("Element clicked - " + e.target.innerHTML);
  }, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zw3g69ry/2/

All of the methods I've mentioned can be called on `document` (as I have done) or called on a specific container element if you only want to look within that container.

Answer (score 0):

This is preferred. Do not simulate a click. Open the URL programmatically.

Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenUrl(ByVal argURL As String)

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Visible = False
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate argURL
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With

objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub